# Run deployment if commit message includes a string?

Tags: git, travis-ci

I am trying to setup my CI so it would perform deployment jobs if commit message includes specific string, which in my case is:

```
chore(release)
```

Currently my configuration looks like this:

```yaml
deploy:
  # deploy to github release
  - provider: releases
    api_key: $GIT_TOKEN
    file_glob: true
    file: "*.vsix"
    skip_cleanup: true
    on:
      tags: false
      all_branches: true
      condition: "$TRAVIS_COMMIT_MESSAGE =~ *release*$"
```

As you can see in this instance I just try to match word "release", but it still doesn't work. Am I doing something wrong? Or maybe it's not possible to match partial string?

My commit message upon testing is:

```
chore(release): version 1.1.6
```

and I run it on master branch (not tags).

Logs give me this message:

```
Skipping a deployment with the releases provider because a custom condition was not met
```

EDIT:

I have also tried something like this:

```
deploy:
  # deploy to github release
  - provider: releases
    if: commit_message =~ /^chore\(release\)/
    api_key: $GIT_TOKEN
    file_glob: true
    file: "*.vsix"
    skip_cleanup: true
    on:
      branch: master
```

Travis logs this out:

> /home/travis/.travis/job_stages: line 565: expected `)'
>   /home/travis/.travis/job_stages: line 565: syntax error near`=~'
>   /home/travis/.travis/job_stages: line 565: `  if [[ ($TRAVIS_BRANCH =
>   commit_message =~ /^chore(release)/) ]]; then'

Comment: Have you read https://docs.travis-ci.com/user/conditions-v1? It links to a way to test conditions locally, and suggests that you might want `commit_message`. Also `*release*$` looks suspicious as a regex *at all*, let alone to match that message format; what is that first asterisk supposed to be repeating, and do you really want zero or more `e`s? I'd suggest using something like https://regex101.com/ to ensure that the regex meets your basic requirements.

Comment: I did read it and did try, will update my question with additional piece of code in a minute, thanks for edit.

Comment: I have added another option I tried, but in second case Travis fails to parse configuration file.

Comment: It *can't* parse it; that's not valid YAML, it's certainly not a valid Travis configuration. `deploy` can't be both an array and an object. Also `^chore\(release\)$` would only match messages that are exactly `chore(release)`, because you've anchored the start *and end* of the string.

Comment: My bad, I did update the second example.

Comment: That error message doesn't seem to match up with what you've posted, I don't know what's going on in there. I suspect the easiest way to do this is going to be with `condition: $TRAVIS_COMMIT_MESSAGE =~ ^chore\(release\)`, it is definitely confusing the way the [`on: condition:` key](https://docs.travis-ci.com/user/deployment/#conditional-releases-with-on) for a deploy doesn't actually expect a [Travis condition](https://docs.travis-ci.com/user/conditions-v1).

Comment: Note that you can test this locally with e.g. `TRAVIS_COMMIT_MESSAGE='chore(release): version 1.1.6'; if [[ $TRAVIS_COMMIT_MESSAGE =~ ^chore\(release\) ]]; then echo 'deploy!'; else echo 'no deploy'; fi`

Comment: Yes, error message was confusing and now I'm ending experimenting with condition, under the deployment object as you mentioned. However your given expression returns 'no match' for me, even though Regex tester https://regex101.com/ does match using your given regular expression

Comment: I am ending up doing `$TRAVIS_COMMIT_MESSAGE =~ release` which works... Not sure why it's not matching chore\(release\)